# FB events tracking on Universal Windows Platform

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, uwp

I want to use Facebook Analytics in a Windows Store application (UWP) with [winsdkfb](https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb).

The login and graph API work perfectly, but installations and other posts to `/application-id/activities` always end with "BadReqeuest".

I checked samples from winsdkfb sources (LoginCpp-UWP). They seem to be broken too.

UPD:
The question is what arguments should be passed in url to track activity events for Universal Windows Platform.

At this time I've found out that winsdkfb doesn't append 'attribution' if advertising identifier is not available. Now I see events from unknown platform in dashboard. Does anybody knows how to specify device operation system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don’t see any actual programming question here, it seems to be a mere “status report”.

Comment: May be it is incorrect formulation of the question. The correct will be "what arguments should be passed in url to correctly track FB event on Universal Windows Platform"